# Visual Studio 2010 rebuilds even if the solution is updated

Tags: visual-studio-2010, compilation, solution

Even if it is freshly built it will complain that the build is outdated and rebuild it ***again***... This wouldn't be much of a problem if it weren't for it also rebuilds when pressing debug (F5) directly after manually building (F7).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im guessing but do you have any files with a datetime stamp thats in the future?  If not then if you could provide a bit more information about the solution your using.

Comment: EDIT: nvm I found the reason... My computer date was set to be 1 day behind... fixed it by changing the date back!

Comment: Cool so by having a computer date in the past all your files had a datetime stamp in the future.  Glad i helped.